# Ubuntu inside Windows 7 as a "virtual PC"?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, microsoft-virtual-pc

I found [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9059/dual-boot-your-pre-installed-windows-7-computer-with-ubuntu/) which describes how to create a dual-boot Windows 7 /  Ubuntu system.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu as a "Virtual PC" inside Windows 7 (i.e. without using VMware or VirtualBox)?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looks interesting, but I didn't want to mess around with the boot manager.  I want to avoid dual-boot scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**.

Even Microsoft's Virtual PC [supports Linux guests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Linux_guests).

Comment: Thanks.  The WIki says Ubuntu must be installed in safe mode -- does that mean it must be run in basic VGA mode?

Comment: @MonopolyMaven [Here are detailed instructions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingUbuntu104LTSOnWindowsVirtualPCOnWindows7.aspx). However, while it's possible to install Ubuntu on Virtual PC, I don't see why you would prefer VPC over VirtualBox or VMWare Workstation. On VB and VMWare, you can simply install Ubuntu without having to worry about any extra configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible right now. VMWare or Virtualbox provide the outer shell of a system to allow such things to work. Windows does not have the tools to run an operating system within it. The only way to use Linux within Windows is to use [Virtual PC,](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) [VMware,](http://www.vmware.com/) [VirtualBox,](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or any such program of that nature.